# How do I use mongoose-seeder, unable to insert data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs

So I installed this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-seeder

It came with mongoose in sub-directory, so I deleted that directory because I have mongoose already in node_modules and it was giving me errors until deleted. The app runs without error, however nothing is created in the myappname-dev database.

As per instructions, created a basic json file (data.json) in /config for mongoose-seeder to parse:

```
{
    "categories": {
        "_model": "Category",
        "title": "Cat1"
    }
}
```

In server.js:

```
var init = require('./config/init')(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    chalk = require('chalk');



var seeder = require('mongoose-seeder'),
    data = require('./config/data.json');





// Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
    }

    seeder.seed(data, function(err, dbData) { });

});
```

Category model:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Category Schema
 */
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Untitled'
    }
});


mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

I am using the meanjs project template, in general I am new to MEAN and having a hard time figuring out how to seed initial data. Another strange thing I noticed is when I create new users in the default meanjs app, they don't appear to be in the users collection of the myappname-dev database.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose) instead. With this, you don't need to write seeding code, but you only write seeding data. And it supports smart reference.